# PHP REST API with nested routes

Tags: php, rest, backend

I want to create a pure **PHP REST API** and I am quite new in backend development field, but I am experienced software developer, so some concepts are known to me.

However, after watching several tutorials on how to create REST API with PHP, all instructors were using *simpler* examples, where no nesting exists.

**Simple Example:**

```
GET /api/category/read.php
```

**However, I want to create something like this:**

```
GET /api/{user_id}/{folder_id}/{file_name}/read.php
```

I am struggling to find any tutorial covering this with PHP. And I have spent several hours trying to figure it out by myself by trying to modify the code I have seen in Tutorial videos. I mean if I do like they do, this would mean manually creating folders in my Project Folder for each `{user_id}` and so forth for each sub-folder... but I do not think that such hardcoding is the solution.

I have found some Stack Overflow questions here relating closely to my question, but none have satisfying answers - makes me wonder that this if this is possible to do at all, but it seems so common (for example, I know that GitHub API has just that support  `/{user}/repos`) so I think it should be doable.

I would be really grateful if someone could help me out how to accomplish my goal. If not else, pointing to a tutorial / documentation that does just that is equivalently appreciated!

Comment: You need to implement `url rewrite`. Which web server you use? Apache/nginx/iis?

Comment: May I invite you to look at my work https://github.com/funilrys/funombi ? It's still in developpement but you may found the `Core\Router()` and the `public/index.php` useful ...

Comment: @SevaKalashnikov I will have to look into that. Because I am develop backend only app. No frontend is there. I just need to provide working REST API. I use Apache through XAMPP.

Comment: @funilrys I will take a look, but I assume that this is connected with frontend development too? As I won't be developing any frontend code. Just REST API.

Comment: @AndroidDev101 Well it's an MVC "framework" but you can do a REST API with it as it can be used for back- and frontend development. I actually wrote some big private project with that "framework" ... Feel free to open an issue there if you do not understand something.

Comment: Have you tried to use a php FrameWork like Symfony ?  Its very handly to develop a RESTFULL API. It will take some time to learn but very interesting.

Comment: @CheikhHAIBALA I read that it's fairly easy to do it PHP Frameworks, but wanted to try it with pure PHP. I will see what I will be able to do.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to create the folder structure to achieve this. It would be more advantageous to use something like [Apache Mod Rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2/5758551) or a framework like [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/master) to help avoid the need to create the file structure you are describing and have a single endpoint for handling specific routes:

Using mod rewrite with Apache2 would work something like:

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^api/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/read /api/read.php?user_id=$1&folder_id=$2&file_name=$3
```

This would provide the URI variables in the $_GET and $_REQUEST supergobals in /api/read.php

---

Using the Laravel framework you can leverage their MVC approach and create dynamic [routes](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing) which can capture the URL vars and deliver them to the desired Controller endpoint:

in your routes file:

```
Route::get('api/{user_id}/{folder_id}/{file_name}/read', Controller@read)
```

in the Controller:

```
public function read(user_id,folder_id,file_name){ /* do stuff */ }
```

There is alot more to know about the specifics of MVC and using Laravel to create an API, however, they have great [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master) and [tutorials](https://laracasts.com/).

Comment: Indeed I have encountered that with PHP frameworks, this can get fairly easy to implement. But I really want to force me use vanilla PHP for this task. I will dig a bit more into some documentation and try to do it, but if all fails, I will accept your answer for Laravel.

Comment: I highly recommend Laravel since it takes care of a lot of the little details for you and provides a lot of functionality up front. But there is no reason you can't achieve the same effect with a careful application of Mod Rewrite and your own routing implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Create a PHP script that receives every request (have Apache direct all requests to it), and then process the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable to split the path into segments, storing the parts in variables of your choice. Then dispatch the request to sub-components as necessary.